# iOS Background task to check for server availability

Tags: ios, swift, networking, background-process

This is my very first post on SO!

I'm a beginner iOS developer and I'm looking for a solution for my Swift app.

Is there any way to implement functionality to ask for a server availibilty on a regular basis (e.g. every 5 min) even when the app is not running. That would only require a simple http request so the app would work as a monitoring tool for a specific server. I tried using Background Fetch but it doesn't seem reliable enough since I can't force it to run every 5 minutes.

Is it possible to achieve that in iOS or maybe there are some better ways to implement such monitoring tool?

EDIT:
To partly answer my question I've found this solution that requires the abuse of Apple policy regarding multitasking:
http://yifan.lu/2013/12/17/unlimited-backgrounding-on-ios/

It requires the use of Audio / AirPlay Background Mode, but I can imagine that Apple won't accept such app in the AppStore. Is there any 100% proper way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You specifically want to track network status while app is in background? If yes, what you are going to do by doing this?

Comment: The app that I'm developing doesn't need any content from the server. The purpose is that I can monitor from my phone if my server is available, so other apps and services can access it. What is more important - I wanted my phone to alert me when the server goes down so I can do something about it and get it back running.

Comment: PLEASE ADD ME SNIP SHOT OF CODE

Comment: To be honest there is not much code to be added here as a snippet. I was asking more on the eventual possibility of implementing such functionality in the iOS app.

Comment: There is no way to do such functionality in iOS. Even the "background" apps (UIBackgroundMode) cannot run entirely freely and without restrictions like a service or daemon etc. on other OSs can.